# React How to conditionally override TextField error color in Material-UI?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using `React Material-UI` library and I want to conditionally override the error color of a TextField.

I need to change the helperText, border, text and required marker color to yellow when the error is of a certain type. Something like that :

[image]

Otherwise, I want to keep the default color(red) for every other type of error. 
I tried to follow the same principle used in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gdsj5) but I couldn't get a grip of all the components that I needed to change and I had to use the `important` keyword almost every time to see a difference.

I have managed to conditionally change the color of the `helperText` like so :

```
                        <TextField
                            label="Name"
                            className={formClasses.textField}
                            margin="normal"
                            variant="outlined"
                            required
                            error={!!errors}
                            helperText={errors && "Incorrect entry."}
                            FormHelperTextProps={{classes: {root: getColorType(AnErrorType)}}}
                        />
```

The `getColorType` will return a CSS object with the property color set to the one that corresponds the given error type. ex:

```
hardRequiredHintText: {
    color: `${theme.palette.warning.light} !important`
},
```

Is there an easier way to override MUI error color and to see it reflected in all the component that uses it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For each type of validation, display a different color, we can **pass params to `makeStyles`**

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const useStyles = params =>
  makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
    }
  }));
const Component = () => {
  const classes = useStyles(someParams)();
```

---

[image]

---

Full code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const useStyles = value =>
  makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
      "& .Mui-error": {
        color: acquireValidationColor(value)
      },
      "& .MuiFormHelperText-root": {
        color: acquireValidationColor(value)
      }
    }
  }));

const acquireValidationColor = message => {
  switch (message) {
    case "Incorrect entry":
      return "green";
    case "Please input":
      return "orange";
    default:
      return "black";
  }
};

const ValidationTextField = ({ helperText }) => {
  const classes = useStyles(helperText)();
  return (
    <TextField
      label="Name"
      margin="normal"
      variant="outlined"
      required
      error={helperText !== ""}
      helperText={helperText}
      className={classes.root}
    />
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const data = ["Incorrect entry", "Please input", ""];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((x, idx) => (
        <ValidationTextField helperText={x} key={idx} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! That's exactly what I needed. I also needed to change the border color :  "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-error": {
                "& fieldset": {
                    borderColor: acquireValidationColor(value),
                },
            },

Answer (score 3):

[image: Output]For Class Based Components

```js
import React from "react";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { withStyles, createStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const commonStyles = (theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {},

    warningStyles: {
      "& .MuiFormLabel-root.Mui-error": {
        color: "orange !important"
      },
      "& .MuiInput-underline.Mui-error:after": {
        borderBottomColor: "orange !important"
      },
      "& .MuiFormHelperText-root.Mui-error": {
        color: "orange !important"
      }
    }
  });

class DemoComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const _text1HasWarning = false;
    const _text2HasWarning = true;
    const _text3HasWarning = false;

    return (
      <>
        <TextField
          error={false}
          className={_text1HasWarning ? classes.warningStyles : null}
          value="Valid Value"
          variant="standard"
          label="Valid label"
          helperText="Valid helper text"
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <TextField
          error={true}
          className={_text2HasWarning ? classes.warningStyles : null}
          value="warning value"
          variant="standard"
          label="warning label"
          helperText="warning helper text"
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <TextField
          error={true}
          className={_text3HasWarning ? classes.warningStyles : null}
          value="error value"
          variant="standard"
          helperText="error helper text"
          label="error label"
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default withStyles(commonStyles)(DemoComponent);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVC9k.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by overriding your Material-UI theme default styles and then wrapping your text field or your  component inside of myTheme

```
import { createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';
 const myTheme = createMuiTheme({
 overrides:{
    MuiInput: {
        underline: {
                '&:after': {
                  backgroundColor: 'any_color_value_in_hex',
                }
             },
          },
       }
   });
   export default myTheme;
```

and then import it into your component and use:

```
import {MuiThemeProvider} from 'material-ui/styles';
import myTheme from './components/myTheme'

<MuiThemeProvider theme = {myTheme}>
  <TextField />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

I hope it helps you.